# Converting API response in XML without tags to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I am very new to XML parsing and I need help in converting a XML API response to a pandas dataframe.

Here is the XML response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response success="true">
  <output><![CDATA[Account Name,Account Code,Level Name,"Item","Customer",Wk1Y23,Wk2Y23
"SVF - Customer Shipping Default","SVF_Shipping_Default.SVF_CSD","Los Fresnos","1.5 G PANSY Matrix Pltr Clear Mix ~ LW85201","Lowes # 90 ~ LW00090",0.0,2.0
"SVF - Customer Shipping Default","SVF_Shipping_Default.SVF_CSD","Los Fresnos","1.5 G PANSY Matrix Pltr Clear Mix ~ LW85201","Lowes # 63 ~ LW00063",0.0,2.0
"SVF - Customer Shipping Default","SVF_Shipping_Default.SVF_CSD","Los Fresnos","1.5 G PANSY Matrix Pltr Clear Mix ~ LW85201","Lowes # 271 ~ LW00271",0.0,4.0]]></output>
</response>
```

As you can see there is not a lot of tagging in this XML. I tried using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse out the xml to a dataframe, but I dont get any data to the dataframe:

```
etree = ET.parse(xml_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree.getroot())))
print(df)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You probably do not want to name a variable `etree`. Please include all `import` lines for [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parsing the text of `<output>` node and pass content into a `read_csv` call using `StringIO`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
...

output_text = ET.parse(xml_data).find("output").text

with StringIO(output_text) as csv_data:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_data)

print(df)
                      Account Name                  Account Code   Level Name  \
0  SVF - Customer Shipping Default  SVF_Shipping_Default.SVF_CSD  Los Fresnos   
1  SVF - Customer Shipping Default  SVF_Shipping_Default.SVF_CSD  Los Fresnos   
2  SVF - Customer Shipping Default  SVF_Shipping_Default.SVF_CSD  Los Fresnos   

                                          Item               Customer  Wk1Y23  \
0  1.5 G PANSY Matrix Pltr Clear Mix ~ LW85201   Lowes # 90 ~ LW00090     0.0   
1  1.5 G PANSY Matrix Pltr Clear Mix ~ LW85201   Lowes # 63 ~ LW00063     0.0   
2  1.5 G PANSY Matrix Pltr Clear Mix ~ LW85201  Lowes # 271 ~ LW00271     0.0   

   Wk2Y23  
0     2.0  
1     2.0  
2     4.0
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait. I am getting the following error: source = open(source, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Do I need to drop the xml response to a file first?

Comment: What line are you receiving that error? `ET.parse` or `read_csv`? If former, I used your setup. If latter, are you using `StringIO`? I will change *xml_data* variable name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you Parfait. I was getting the error because I was not writing out the XML response out to a file and reading it back in. I did that and your solution works now.